# Cambiar la vista de edición de un procedimiento almacenado en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Holas

Estoy usando SQL Server 2014 y al darle a la opción de modificar un procedimiento almacenado se muestran de la siguiente manera:

```
USE [EFacturador]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[paVentaListar]    Script Date: 20/12/2018 06:24:38 p.m. ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[paVentaListar]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'-- =============================================
-- Author:      Alcibiades Palestini
-- Create date: 19/12/2018
-- Description: Listado de ventas
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[paVentaListar] 
    @FechaIni   date,
    @FechaFin   date
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT Cp.FechaEmision, Cp.NumCp, TipoCp.Descripcion, PersonaNombre AS ''Cliente''
    FROM [SanJuanv97].[dbo].Cp, [SanJuanv97].[dbo].TipoCp
    WHERE Cp.IDTipoCp = TipoCp.PKID AND (Fecha BETWEEN ''01/06/2018'' AND ''31/12/2018'') AND TipoCp.TipoCp = ''Venta''
END
' 
END
```

Cuando debería salir de la siguiente manera:

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Alcibiades Palestini
-- Create date: 19/12/2018
-- Description: Listado de ventas
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[paVentaListar] 
    @FechaIni   date,
    @FechaFin   date
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT Cp.FechaEmision, Cp.NumCp, TipoCp.Descripcion, PersonaNombre AS 'Cliente'
    FROM [SanJuanv97].[dbo].Cp, [SanJuanv97].[dbo].TipoCp
    WHERE Cp.IDTipoCp = TipoCp.PKID AND (Fecha BETWEEN '01/06/2018' AND '31/12/2018') AND TipoCp.TipoCp = 'Venta'
END
```

Cualquier ayuda se agradece ya que me es muy molesto tener que estar modificando mis procedimientos almacenados como se está mostrando. Gracias.

Comment: Saludos compatriota ¿Cuál es la pregunta en sí?

Answer (score 0):

De hecho te aconsejo que añadas las siguientes lineas a tu codigo

```
USE [EFacturador]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[paVentaListar]    Script Date: 20/12/2018 06:24:38 p.m. ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
```

Por seguridad estables en la primera linea(USE [EFacturador]) la base datos que vas a usar.
Por otro lado (SET ANSI_NULLS ON) lo que hace es decir que no va a retornar nada si tu sp no tine resultados.

Espero te sirva.